# Duplicate Movie Clip Lowest Depth

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am using some actionscript I found in a tutorial to duplicate a movie clip. It works beautifully, but the only issue is the duplicated movie clip is placed on top of all other layers. I would like to cover part of the flash window.

I've tried searching for a way to lower the depth of the duplicated movie clip, but nothing I've tried so far works.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
for(i=0; i<500; i++) {
    var t:MovieClip = snow_mc.duplicateMovieClip("snow"+i,i);
    t._x = random(750);
    t._y = random(550);
    t._xscale = t._yscale = random(80)+20;
    t.gotoAndPlay(Math.round(random(81)+1));
}
```

I've tried changing the ("snow"+i,i); part to ("snow"+i,-1000000); or something like that because based off of http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001290.html that should be the depth integer controller. It didn't work and I've also tried it on several other pieces to the code with no luck.

Anyone know if there is a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there something else on stage that you want all your duplicated clips to appear under?

Comment: everytime you add something to the stage its natural order will be on top, meaning if you add the item inside a container it will only be on top of its self in the container.